# mongoose cursor batchSize

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how to iterate the cursor batch documents in case that the batchSize is defined ?
example, when the batchSize defined to be equal to 50 , is there any way to iterate that 50 sub documents ?

```
var myCursor = collection.find().cursor({batchSize:50});
mycursor('on',function(doc){

})
```

Comment: did you find the answer to this, i would like `doc` to be an array of 50 documents in this example.

Answer (score 4):

Giving an Update to May 2022 Solution for whom want to add Populate within Cursor BatchSize.

- The usecase here is that for every Streamed Document, corresponding to 1 Query to MongoDB. For example `collection` has 1000 records. Say you use Stream  APIs or equivalent

```
(async () => {
  /** @description - Good Performance */
  const stream = MongooseModel.find({}).cursor();
  for await (const doc of stream) {
    console.log(doc);
  }
  /** @description - Worse Performance */
  const stream = MongooseModel.find({}).populate({path: 'fieldX'}).batchSize(1).cursor();
  for await (const doc of stream) {
    console.log(doc);
  }
})();
```

- This will create a huge dropdown on Performance approximately 50 times from my comparison (25000 records / sec Non-Populate) vs (500 records / sec Populate 1 field)
- The reason is that for each `streamed / 1-cursor` document created. Mongoose send 1 query to MongoDB via its Driver.
- So we use `batchSize` along with cursor, for example `{batchSize: 100}`. So for the `collection` that has `1000 records`. Mongoose populate and left-join `1000 / 100 == 10` times instead of `1000` times

```
(async () => {
  /** @description - Better Performance - Theoretically without BUGs */
  const stream = MongooseModel.find({}).populate({path: 'fieldX'}).batchSize(100).cursor();
  for await (const doc of stream) {
    console.log(doc);
  }
})();
```

- However. Mongoose has BUGS !!! Older Mongoose version: Before v6.2 even though you specify `batchSize` it still not reduce the Query !!!
- `@see` {`@link` https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9365 }
- `@see` {`@link` https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11509 }
- `@refer` {`@link` https://thecodebarbarian.com/cursors-in-mongoose-45 }
- `@alternative` {`@link` https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3683 }

Comment: can you give space between link and } it add  %7D at end of link

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var myCursor = collection.find({}).cursor({batchSize:50});
myCursor.eachAsync((doc) => {
   ...
});
```

Batch sizes are just for performance optimisation and will not give you a 50 object chunk.

You will still have to process each doc individually.

Comment: im trying to run this on mongoose , and unfortunately mongoose doesn't have hasNext like mongoDB

Comment: Thanks , but eachAsync iterate over all the documents that answer the query , i want a way to use the each 50 batch document that i defined .