# Mongoose Cursor: http bulk request from collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async-await, rxjs

I have a problem which is relevant to `rxJS` and bulk HTTP requests from the huge collection (1M+ docs)

I have the following code, with quite simple logic. I push all the docs from the collection to `allplayers` array and making bulk 20 `HTTP` requests to API at once (guess you understand why it's limited) So, the code works fine, but I guess it's time to refactor it from this:

```
        const cursor = players_db.find(query).lean().cursor();
        cursor.on('data', function(player) { allPlayers.push(player); });
        cursor.on('end', function() {
            logger.log('warng',`S,${allPlayers.length}`);
            from(allPlayers).pipe(
                mergeMap(player => getPlayer(player.name, player.realm),20),
            ).subscribe({
                next: player => console.log(`${player.name}@${player.realm}`),
                error: error => console.error(error),
                complete: () => console.timeEnd(`${updatePlayer.name}`),
            });
        });
```

As for now, I'm using `find` with `cursor` with (`batchSize`), but if I understood this right (via `.length`), and according to this question: {[mongoose cursor batchSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118590/mongoose-cursor-batchsize)} `batchSize` is just a way of optimization and it's not return me array of X docs.

> So what should I do now and what operator should I choose for `rxJS`?

For example I could form arrays with necessary length (like 20) and transfer it to `rxJS` as I use it before. But I guess there should be another way, where I could use `rxJS` inside this `for promise loop`

```
    const players = await players_db.find(query).lean().cursor({batchSize: 10});
    for (let player = await players.next(); player != null; player = await players.next()) {
        //do something via RxJS inside for loop
    }
```

Also I found this question {[Best way to query all documents from a mongodb collection in a reactive way w/out flooding RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362449/best-way-to-query-all-documents-from-a-mongodb-collection-in-a-reactive-way-w-ou)} which also relevant to my problem and I understand the logic, but don't the syntax of it. I also know that `cursor` variable isn't a doc I cann't do anything *useful* with it. Or actually I could?

> 1. rxJS's `bufferCount` is a quite interesting operator
> 2. https://gist.github.com/wellcaffeinated/f908094998edf54dc5840c8c3ad734d3 probable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end I found that rxJS isn't needed (but can be used) for this case.

The solution was quite simple and using just `MongoCursor`:

```
async function BulkRequest (bulkSize = 10) {
    try {
       let BulkRequest_Array = [];
       const cursor = collection_db.find({}).lean().cursor({batchSize: bulkSize});
       cursor.on('data', async (doc) => {
           BulkRequest_Array.push(/*any function or axios instance*/)
            if (BulkRequest_Array.length >= bulkSize) {
                cursor.pause();
                console.time(`========================`);;
                await Promise.all(BulkRequest_Array);
                BulkRequest_Array.length = 0;
                cursor.resume();
                console.timeEnd(`========================`);
            }
       }
    } catch (e) {
       console.error(e)
    }
}

BulkRequest();
```